# Excel Vlookup dupicate with different values

Tags: excel, database, excel-formula, vlookup

I need to create the summary of all the parts Invoiced downloading the file updating on my work ERP software. There are few duplicates in part numbers with different qty. invoiced. how to calculate sum of both without making a new table from it.

Summary report -

[image]

In this part number - BX4-07-9021-01A

has 2 columns in my ERP report -

[image]

The formula i used in my summary report to check the qty. invoiced -
=VLOOKUP('Visual Part P.O. Req.'!A3,'Order Number 18900 A'!E:H,4,FALSE)

In this 'Visual Part P.O. Req. ' is the summary report
and 'Order Number 18900 A' is the file downloaded from ERP

Comment: Use `SUMIFS` instead.

Comment: Pivot Table will be easy may be to create a summary report?